# Unwanted JavaScript translation by Django

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization

I've a simple JS script:

```
document.write(gettext('Do tłumaczenia'));
```

written in Polish and wanted to translate it into english and german. I did the docummentation stuff and now english and german versions work fine, but polish is also translated into english, which is unwanted behavior. Am I doing sth wrong?

Just added js_info_dict, url, compiled messages with -d djangojs and included javascript_catalog before my script inside a template.

I know I could solve this by creating 'pl' locale and translating polish into polish, but ... this is weak.

Any ideas? Thx.

UPDATE: translating templates works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that javascript_catalog uses 'en' by default when english translation is found but current's not. So modified urls and added

```
{% if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'pl' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.null_javascript_catalog %}"></script>
{% else %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>
{% endif %}
```